# JavaScript: use an object returned by function without object of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in JavaScript/jQuery. Wondering if there is any better way to return an object by a function.

```
//this is the Object creator.
function makeNewPlayer(name, score) {
    var player = {};
    player.name = name;
    player.score = score;

    return player;
};
```

This is how I use the function.

```
var player_info = makeNewPlayer('Bob' ,100);
```

However, when I use the object, I need to call it like this:

```
player_info.player.name
player_info.player.score
```

It looks stupid, any way to use the object directly like this?

```
player_info.name
player_info.score
```

**edit:**

As I don't know how many object will be created by the function.
Let say there is a for loop to make score_1, score_2 etc.

```
function makeNewPlayer(name, score) {
    var player = {};
    player.name = name;

    for(i=0, i<number_of_score, i++){
        eval("player.score_" + i) = score[i];
    };

    return player;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `new`.

I copied some text from [my blog](http://holmeshe.me/javascript-tutorial-for-experienced-programmer-object-dictionary/#Constructor) that happened to resolve your doubts:

> A constructor is a special function used for creating an object:
>
> Example:

```
function StarkIndustries(name, birth) {
  this.name = name;
  this.birth = birth;
}
var iron1 = new StarkIndustries('iron01', 2017);
var iron2 = new StarkIndustries('iron02', 2017);
alert(iron1.name);
alert(iron2.name);
```

> Result:

```
iron01
iron02
```

> By adding new before a function, the function is turned into a
>   constructor that constructs an object.

But it is dangerous to call a function designed as a constructor
without new, because it will modify the global object `window`. So sanity check inside the constructor is required:

```
if (!(this instanceof StarkIndustries)) {
  warn("StarkIndustries is a constructor and should be called with `new`");
}
```

Back to your code, it should be:

```
function makeNewPlayer(name, score) {
    this.name = name
    this.score = score
};

var iron1 = new makeNewPlayer('iron01', 2017);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructing assignment to declare global or locally scoped variables

```js
//this is the Object creator.
function makeNewPlayer(name, score) {
  var player = {};
  player.name = name
  player.score = score

  return player;
};

var player_info = makeNewPlayer("Bob", 100);

{
  let {name: _name, score} = player_info;
  // do stuff with `_name`, `score`
  console.log(_name, score);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeNewPlayer(name, score) {
   return {name, score};
};

let players = [];
// in for loop -- sample code only, you need to supply name & score
{
   players.push(makeNewPlayer(name, score));
}
```

Comment: What if I don't know how many object will be created by the function?
Let say there is a for loop to make score_1, score_2 etc, how can I handle this?

Comment: In this case, what concerns you is to find a proper collection object.  In most cases, Array is a good choice, e.g., let's name it players. in your for-loop, just call players.push(newPlayer) to add the new created player to this array.

Answer (score 0):

Aside for the fact that "Bob" should be in quotes, it's working fine for me.

```
var player_info = makeNewPlayer('Bob', 100);
```

and then I am able to access it just fine like this:

```
player_info.name
player_info.score
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary constructor function inside of your function :

```
function makeNewPlayer(name, score){
  const Player = function(name, score){
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
  };

  return new Player(name, score);
}
```

You can also use an external function instead of a nested one.

Answer (score 0):

With no change to your function, i am able to get the output the way you want it

```
player_info.name
player_info.score
```

Check out the snippet below

```js
//this is the Object creator.
function makeNewPlayer(name, score) {
  var player = {};
  player.name = name
  player.score = score

  return player;
};

var player_info = makeNewPlayer("Bob", 100);
console.log(player_info.name);
console.log(player_info.score);
```